# Different Citation Styles in modernCV

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have different types of publications in my CV and would like to use a different format for all of them. I can do this using the printbibliography package, but the citations themselves look the same.

The desired behavior is that it lists conference publications as C1, C2, C3... and journals as J1, J2, J3... Then when I cite them I'd like to have them referred to as [C1], [J2] and so on, but it does not work.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,roman,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

\nocite{*}
\usepackage[maxbibnames=99,defernumbers=true,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{publications.bib}

\moderncvstyle{classic}                     
\moderncvcolor{red}                         
\name{Sparky}{McSparkface}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Publications}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{C#1.}
\printbibliography[title = Refereed Conference Publications,keyword = conference]
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{J#1.}
\printbibliography[title = Journal Publications, keyword = journal,resetnumbers = true]
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{U#1.}
\printbibliography[title = Technical Reports and Preprints, keyword = unpub,resetnumbers = true]

I want to cite the conference using \texttt{cite} like this C1, but it does this: \cite{conf1}. 


\end{document}
```

I am using the following .bib file:

```
@misc{unpubA,
year = {2024},
author = {Albus Dumbeldore and Severus Snape},
title = {How to Discipline Young Wizards},
note= {In Submission},
keywords = {unpub}
}

@misc{unpubB,
year = {2024},
author = {Charles Xavier and Erik Lenscherr},
title = {Mind Over Matter: Empirical and Theoretical Analysis},
keywords = {unpub},
note = {In Submission}
}


@inproceedings{conf1,
    author    = {Tony Stark and Bruce Banner},
    title     = {Creating Embodied Artificial Intelligence: Risks and Lessons Learned},
    booktitle   = {In Proceedings of the 31st Conference on Artificial Intelligence},
    year      = {2024},
    keywords ={conference}
}



@article{jour1,
author = {Bruce Wayne and Clark Kent},
title = {Money, Power and Flight},
year = {2023},
issue_date = {June 2023},
volume = {1},
number = {1},
journal = {Transactions on Capitalism},
month = {jun},
articleno = {7},
keywords ={journal}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For proper handling of prefixes for citation labels, you'll want to use `refcontext`s and their `labelprefix` option. This could look as follows

```
\documentclass[10pt,roman,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\usepackage[maxbibnames=99,defernumbers=true,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\nocite{*}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{red}
\name{Sparky}{McSparkface}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{unpubA,
  year     = {2024},
  author   = {Albus Dumbeldore and Severus Snape},
  title    = {How to Discipline Young Wizards},
  note     = {In Submission},
  keywords = {unpub},
}
@misc{unpubB,
  year     = {2024},
  author   = {Charles Xavier and Erik Lenscherr},
  title    = {Mind Over Matter: Empirical and Theoretical Analysis},
  keywords = {unpub},
  note     = {In Submission},
}
@inproceedings{conf1,
  author    = {Tony Stark and Bruce Banner},
  title     = {Creating Embodied Artificial Intelligence: Risks and Lessons Learned},
  booktitle = {In Proceedings of the 31st Conference on Artificial Intelligence},
  year      = {2024},
  keywords  = {conference},
}
@article{jour1,
  author     = {Bruce Wayne and Clark Kent},
  title      = {Money, Power and Flight},
  year       = {2023},
  issue_date = {June 2023},
  volume     = {1},
  number     = {1},
  journal    = {Transactions on Capitalism},
  month      = {jun},
  articleno  = {7},
  keywords   = {journal},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Publications}
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=C]
\printbibliography[title = Refereed Conference Publications,keyword = conference]
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=J]
\printbibliography[title = Journal Publications, keyword = journal,resetnumbers = true]
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=U]
\printbibliography[title = Technical Reports and Preprints, keyword = unpub,resetnumbers = true]

I want to cite the conference using \texttt{cite} like this C1, but it does this: \cite{conf1}.


\end{document}
```

[image: Publication list with citations in desired format]